# how to get all row in mysql only the same column value in two table

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing event website, after create the event, the site give the event url to user like this

```
www.event.com/?h=6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c
6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c
```

this parameter is record as id(primary key) in eventTable. What my problem is i create a comment box, all of the comment is record at commentTable and it has e_id column, the value is same as id from eventTable. how to get all of the comment from commentTable when event id is same as e_id from commentTable;
[image]

Answer (score 1):

SQL provides JOIN clause to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them. here you can use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM eventTable join  commentTable on commentTable.e_id=eventTable.id where commentTable.e_id=6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c
```

find more about [SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: doesn't need to use join here. Because here we don't need data from both tables. And if there is a event id called 6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c in cooment table, definitely that id should be in event table also.

Answer (score 1):

The event id is visible in url. That means , You are using GET method.You have bind event id to url as "h". So we can load the comments for the relevant event as follows.

```
SELECT comments FROM commentTable WHERE e_id=$_GET['h'];
```

Answer (score 0):

by a join query like this

```
select * from commentTable inner join  eventTable on commentTable.e_id=eventTable.id where commentTable.e_id=111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM commentTable WHERE e_id = event_id
```

`event_id` is event id parameter, in your example 6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple query with a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT name, comment FROM commentTable WHERE e_id = 6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c
6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple just a where clause in select statement.

```
select name, comment from commentTable where e_id= '6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c
```

6997287a21a94875a1d827f9e2790a6c'

Answer (score 0):

selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns and check for event id which you receive from `$_GET`

```
$eventId = $_GET['h'];

select e.id, e.title, e.date, c.name, c.comment from eventTable as e, commentTable as c where e.id = c.e_id and e.id = $eventId;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

then do the following code,

```
$event_id=$_GET['h'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM commentTable WHERE e_id ='$event_id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Query Failed".mysql_error());
$row =mysql_fetch_array($result);
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Hokie. ;) you can select each value like this    ` echo $row['comment']; `